# Does length of an automation script directly determine its likelihood of failing?

Tags: python, selenium, scripting, automation, appium

What I mean is, if my script is 1000 lines of code long, is it more likely to fail then if it was only a hundred lines long, with everything else being equal?

It seems like my tests are failing randomly just because my script is long

Comment: Not really, so long as the coed isn't erroneous, it should be fine. I would debug it, there's probably some missing or extra code that doesn't belong (or causes failing loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longer a script you write is, the more chances you have for making a mistake while you are writing it.

That said, it is not the case that

> tests are failing randomly just because my script is long

Your tests are likely failing because there is an error somewhere, either in the tests or the logic in your script.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant with all else being equal. Can length alone contribute.

Comment: No. Python scripts can be far longer than 1000 lines without causing issues. While some programs may, eventually, have problems because of their literal length, the size would be incredibly massive, and probably limited by the operating system instead of Python.

Comment: Interesting. Debugging it is. Thank you!

Comment: A script too long within a single test can lead to a test failing randomly depending on how the web page is implemented. Each test launch a new browser, so executing too many commands can lead to a memory overflow which would crash the page and make the test fail.